# Triple integral and region of integration: $f(x,y,z)=z^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate $\iiint_s f(x,y,z) \;dxdydz$ for $f(x,y,z) = z^2$ and $S$ the region bounded by $z=0$, $x^2 + z = 1$ and $y^2 + z=1$

I've already plotted the region but I am really having difficult to find the integration region.

I tried the following:

1)$0\leq z \leq 1$, $-sqrt{1-z} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-z}$ but I couldnt find the x variation (same for $x$ instead of $y$)

But maybe there is an easy one that I can't see

I would be glad if someone could explain how to write, step by step, a region.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: I have no doubt you are having an extremely difficult time trying to characterize the region of integration. If a possible way to do this exists, I don't know it.

Since you've already graphed the bounding surfaces, you probably recognized right away that the region of integration has some very nice symmetry: 1) symmetry under interchanging $x$ with $y$; 2) symmetry under reflection through the $x$-axis; and 3) symmetry under reflection through the $y$-axis. That's a fancy way of demonstrating what was probably also visually very obvious from the graph: the region of integration can be divided into four equivalent sections.

Try your hand at characterizing the region of integration for just one of these sections. You'll find that all of the complications that were getting in your way beforehand are now gone.

Comment: Thanks, my friend. Using your hint and the shadow method, I could find the region and the integral